# Active admin: reset password does not show an error after token is expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, reset-password

When I generate the reset password link sent through active admin forgot passoword I am able to change the password and log in to the dashboard but when i try to use the same link again to change password it does nothing and redirects to same page. It shows no errors even when i enter empty passwords. I want it to show an error that the token is expired

the same log is generated every time I submit the form.

> AdminUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."reset_password_token" = '14ad4bc9d075cbb5ed8057c9518848e448e56beab6430ff1d3c7459771a79662'  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["reset_password_token", "14ad4bc9d075cbb5ed8057c9518848e448e56beab6430ff1d3c7459771a79662"]]
>   method=PUT path=/admin/password format=html controller=ActiveAdmin::Devise::PasswordsController action=update status=200 duration=606.45 view=570.88 db=0.64 time=2016-07-26 12:25:20 UTC category=web ip=127.0.0.1 params={"admin_user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}

I have no idea why I gives 200 status.Any idea where I should start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrided the devise `update` method in `Devise::PasswordsController` and add a line to show errors `flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`
basically it doesnt show erros if `resource.errors.empty?` is false.

here is the updated method

```
 # PUT /resource/password
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.empty?
      resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
      if Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password
        flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
        set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_flashing_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message(:notice, :updated_not_active) if is_flashing_format?
      end
      respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    else
      flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```